# Why is Mongo JSON query failing to execute by runMangoAggregation Processor Nifi?

Tags: json, apache-nifi

I have a json query which is throwing exception rom Nifi.

```
Error running MongoDB aggregation query.: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{
"$group": {
"_id": {
"X": "$X",
"Y_DT": "$Y_DT",
"Z": "$Z"
},
"adj": {"$sum": "$adj" },
"bjc": {"$sum": "$bjc" },
"jbc": {"$sum": "$jbc" },
"mnk": {"$sum": "$mnk"}
}
}"; line: 1, column: 1]
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.util.ArrayList` out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: (String)"{
```

The actually query which I am firing from runMangoAggregation processor

```
{
"$group": {
"_id": {
"X": "$X",
"Y_DT": "$Y_DT",
"Z": "$Z"
},
"adj": {"$sum": "$adj" },
"bjc": {"$sum": "$bjc" },
"jbc": {"$sum": "$jbc" },
"mnk": {"$sum": "$mnk"}
}
}
```

What could be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The query supposed to used @ runMongoAggregation is.

```
   [{
"$group": {
"_id": {
"X": "$X",
"Y_DT": "$Y_DT",
"Z": "$Z"
},
"adj": {"$sum": "$adj" },
"bjc": {"$sum": "$bjc" },
"jbc": {"$sum": "$jbc" },
"mnk": {"$sum": "$mnk"}
}
}]
```

the missing square brackets